# Writing a for loop to add 1 to each element in a vector for R

Tags: r, for-loop

Apologies for the dumb question, but I've just begun teaching myself programming and working with R and have been stuck on this question for a couple of days. I'm creating a vector that has three elements to it and then trying to write a for loop that adds one to each element. This is what I have so far.

````
```{r}
vec <- c(3, 1, 4) 
for (j in 1:dim(vec)[1]
vec = vec + 1
}
````

I tried looking at some examples and this was the closest I got, and I feel like it should work, but I keep getting errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `vec + 1` is all you need.

Comment: `vec <- vec + 1` (without a for loop) is what you need, but as an aside, `for (j in seq_along(vec))` is an alternative to your `for ..` line. You would then have `vec[j] = vec[j] + 1` if a for loop was absolutely necessary

Answer (score 3):

R has vector aware functions. Most classic math operations are 'vectorized' .

The other trick is that some vectorized functions features recycling.

So when you do

```
v <- c(1, 2, 4)
v <- v + 1
```

The number 1 is recycled as a vector that matches the size of v.

Given this, v+1 is the same as

```
v <- c(1, 2, 4) + c(1, 1, 1)
```

Note your for loop above has various syntax errors

```
for (j in 1:dim(vec)[1] vec = vec + 1 }
```

Should be

```
for (j in 1:length(vec)) { vec[j] <- vec[j] + 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

R is built around vectors, so functions and arithmetic can be performed on entire vectors. `for` loops will be much slower than making use of R's native vector-based operations. Just remove the `for` loop and it will work. As Pierre commented, only `vec + 1` is needed.

```
vec <- c(3, 1, 4) 
vec <- vec + 1
print(vec)
#[1] 4 2 5
```

Though you would never do it this way, to fix your loop, do this:

```
vec <- c(3, 1, 4) 
for (j in 1:length(vec)){
    vec[j] = vec[j] + 1
}
print(vec)
#[1] 4 2 5
```